# Compatibility of Firefox with selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

What would be the required version of selenium standalone server jar (while using selenium web-driver in Eclipse) which is compatible with latest version of Firefox (32)?

Comment: did you try the latest version of selenium standalone server jar

Comment: @Rishi could you please provide me a better link to download latest version of selenium standalone server jar?

Comment: Please download it from the  site http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ v2.44.0

Answer (score 0):

The recommended version is the 2.43.1, but I had problems using just the selenium standalone server.
I needed install the version 18 of guava.

If you are using maven, include this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maven doesn't come into use here.
So do you suggest me to install guava as well?